# How to get values in function element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I don't know how to get special value in element like this:

My HTML:

```
<div class="medium-6 medium-centered row" id="image-box">
    <% @files = Dir["app/assets/images/*.*"] %>
    <% @files.each do |f| %>
    <div class="th" onclick="openimage(this)">
        <img src="/assets/<%= f.split('/').last %>"  width="50" height="55" id="abc" />
    </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

My javascript:

```
function openimage(element) {
    console.log(element)
}
```

And my element return like this:

```
"<div class="th" onclick="openimage(this)">
    <img src="/assets/line_icon.png" width="50" height="55" id="abc">
</div>"
```

I want to get this line "/assets/line_icon.png", but I don't know how to do that. Please! help me.

p/s: I must add "this" in `onclick="openimage(this)`, because I'm using loop in ruby on rails

Comment: What do you have in @files? File name (e.g. line_icon.jpg)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your js function to:

```
function openimage(element) {
       console.log($(element).find("img").attr("src"))
    }
```

Comment: Yeah! it's work! I don't know I can use .find() :), thanks you so much!

Answer (score 1):

In the core of your function

```
 var tempSrc =$(element).find("img").attr("src");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change little bit of your code like:

```
onclick="openimage(this, event)"
```

pass the event in the onclick handler too.

and in your js you can do this:

```
function openimage(e, event) {
  console.log(event.toElement.getAttribute('src'));
}
```

```js
function openimage(e, event) {
  console.log(event.toElement.getAttribute('src'));
}
```

```html
<div class="th" onclick="openimage(this, event)">
  <img src="/assets/convert/" width="50" height="55" id="thumnail" />
</div>
```